# Dynamic clickable links using Javascript on FormAssembly forms - not within a repeatable section

Tags: javascript, dynamic, hyperlink, clickable

Need to create a list of different links on a page with the same variable appended to the end of each url.

e.g.:

https://example.tfaforms.net/formA?urlParam=ABCDEFG

https://example.tfaforms.net/formB?urlParam=ABCDEFG

https://example.tfaforms.net/formC?urlParam=ABCDEFG

https://example.tfaforms.net/formD?urlParam=ABCDEFG

FormAssembly provide an example on this page where they demonstrate how to create a repeatable section on a page with dynamic clickable links using Javascript to replace the url appended parameter in html code:

https://www.formassembly.com/blog/dynamic-clickable-links/

**They use this html code: **

`<a href="https://instanceName.tfaforms.net/secondFormID?urlParam=#" class="clickableLink">Text to display for your link</a>`

**Alongside this javascript:**

```
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-JAW99MJVpJBGcbzEuXk4Az05s/XyDdBomFqNlM3ic+I="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   //declares function to replace href in hyperlink text with value of a field in repeat section 
  function dynamicLinks(linkClass, fieldId) {
      //creates selector statement with fieldId
      var selection = 'input[id^="' + fieldId + '"]';
      //intializes array to store new links
      var linkArr = [];
      //adds links to array from field in repeat section
      $(selection).each(function() {
        linkArr.push($(this).val());
      });
       //replaces the class of hyperlinks with values from the link array
       $(linkClass).attr("href", function(i, origLink) {
      return origLink.replace(/#/, linkArr[i]);    
       });
     };
  // This is the field ID to update with your value from Salesforce field ID
  dynamicLinks(".clickableLink","tfa_2");  
});
</script>
```

However, my use case is multiple links off of a contents-like list, all with the same urlParam=# at the end of the urls. Also I do not need the repeatable section functionality just need the Javascript to find all # in html and replace with the same tfa_2.

Using the FormAssembly example code I thought I could build out the html on each line of links and it would replace each # with the tfa_2 - however, it only performs the replace function on the first link.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using a different class for each link:

```
<a href="https://example.tfaforms.net/formA?urlParam=#" class="clickableLink1">Text to display for your link</a>
<a href="https://example.tfaforms.net/formB?urlParam=#" class="clickableLink2">Text to display for your link</a>
<a href="https://example.tfaforms.net/formC?urlParam=#" class="clickableLink3">Text to display for your link</a>
```

Then I added each class as a line at the end of the script separated by a semicolon:

```
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-JAW99MJVpJBGcbzEuXk4Az05s/XyDdBomFqNlM3ic+I="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   //declares function to replace href in hyperlink text with value of a field in repeat section 
  function dynamicLinks(linkClass, fieldId) {
      //creates selector statement with fieldId
      var selection = 'input[id^="' + fieldId + '"]';
      //intializes array to store new links
      var linkArr = [];
      //adds links to array from field in repeat section
      $(selection).each(function() {
        linkArr.push($(this).val());
      });
       //replaces the class of hyperlinks with values from the link array
       $(linkClass).attr("href", function(i, origLink) {
      return origLink.replace(/#/, linkArr[i]);    
       });
     };
  // This is the field ID to update with your value from Salesforce field ID
  dynamicLinks(".clickableLink1","tfa_2");
  dynamicLinks(".clickableLink2","tfa_2");
  dynamicLinks(".clickableLink3","tfa_2");
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps!